# Redmine under sub-directory on nginx

Tags: nginx, redmine, thin

My vhost configuration: http://pastebin.com/ZyXUmQtx (only one domain on this installation)

I've been racking my head and Google for a solution the last two days and can't quite seem to come up with a solution that works.

My setup (from the above configuration):

- IP.Board 3.4 installation in %root_domain%/forums/
- IP.Content 2.3 installation in %root_domain/forums/ (with external access `index.php` on the top-level)
- Redmine 2.2.2 install at `/usr/share/redmine` (this is working because Thin is running and there are no errors in either log file)
- Stale phpMyAdmin configuration at `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/` that also kinda doesn't load html/css properly.
- Symlink to `/usr/share/redmine/public` to `/srv/www/tiberian-genesis.net/public_html/redmine`

**I'm trying to get redmine setup to run under `%root_domain%/redmine/`**, but I keep getting a 404 page from my IP.Content installation.

Accessing it takes me to the url: `/redmine/login?back_url=http://redmine_thin_servers/redmine/` (which now that notice it, it seems to not like my upstream...)

In case someone requests the Thin configuration file:

```
---
pid: /var/run/thin/redmine.pid
group: tgmod
prefix: /redmine
timeout: 30
log: /var/log/thin/redmine.log
max_conns: 1024
require: []

max_persistent_conns: 512
environment: production
user: tgmod
servers: 1
daemonize: true
chdir: /usr/share/redmine
socket: /var/run/thin/redmine.sock
```

I'm out of ideas here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up setting it up on a sub-domain. I wanted to try to proxy it on a sub-directory, but my main website kept interfering with the rules.